# How to convert csv double data into timestamp using java

Tags: java, plot, type-conversion

Hi just want to ask how to import the csv file and convert one column from double data type into timestamp (for plotting), the data is like 42824.7648347222 and I want to convert it into ss:mm:hh. So how to achieve it in Java?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How would 42824.7648347222 represent a timestamp ?

Comment: Well, it is from other people's file, but it contains information ss.mm.hh and  dd/mm/yyyy. If I try to convert it from excel it works. To be honest I don't know how it represents...